# Unable to disable a required field in CRM 2011 online

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

The 'estimatedvalue' attribute of the opportunity entity is marked as being required.  I have it on the form, but have marked it as being disabled, both through the Form UI customization, as well as using javascript, but some other javascript is re-enabling the form after I've disabled it.

The best solution I have so far is disabling the attribute from the callback of a timeout: `setTimeout("CommonLib.setDisabled('estimatedvalue', true);", 1);`.  When the field loads, it loads as disabled, then some other js is enabling the field, then the callback from the timeout runs and disables it again, so you see the field go from grayed out, to black, to grayed out.

There are two other attributes that I've disabled and they stay disabled, but the estimatedvalue is the only one that is actually required, so I'm guessing it has something to do with that.

Any ideas as to what is re-enabling the field?

Comment: Perhaps, there are built-in scripts which triggered after customized scripts are finished to execute(your script). I guess this is the only explanation for this behavior.

Comment: I was assuming that some other script was running, I'm just unable to find it or track it down...

Comment: I've tried disabling the field you indicate (estimatedvalue on Opportunity) and it works ok. I am unable to 're-enable' it and it isn't happening over a short period of time (~ 5 minutes). This is using CRM 2011 with rollup 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think it has anything to do with the requirement level but @Anwar may be one explanation. Could you double check if some other custom script might be enabling the field?

I just tried following with the task where subject is the required field and it seems to be working fine:

Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get('subject').setDisabled(true);

Comment: There has to be some other CRM javascript that is running after the CRM onLoad event fires.  I tried doing a text search for 'estimatedvalue' and was unable to find it anywhere in the scripts where it was getting enabled.  Any idea how to track down what script is enabling it?  My js skills are not the best.

Comment: You could try to debug the script and may be able to find out where does it get enabled again.Example, function disableOnLoad() { debugger; .....// rest of your code }. In the IE open an opportunity record, go to Tools - > F12 developer tools, and start script debugging. Refresh the dialog and you can debug crm scripts as well.

Comment: the javascript debugging is going to be the only way to actually figure out what is causing the re-enabling, but who knows how long it would take to go through of all Microsoft's javascript.  Instead I've opted to leave my hack in as is.  Thanks for your help.